# Dropdown size login button issue (Meteor, Bootstrap 3)

Tags: drop-down-menu, meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3

I just migrated to bootstrap 3. I used the account-ui-bootstrap-dropdown package which is now irrelevant I think the account-ui-bootstrap-3 does the job.

As you can see in the image, it is now pretty messed up

[image: my login button]

I just saw that text-based form controls with the .form-control class applied are now 100% wide by default. Wrap inputs inside  to control input widths. But it doesn't work for me.

I'm just a normal guy, I just want a normal login system :)

Thank you all for your help

Comment: Wow! Thats pretty ugly :) What browser are you using?

Comment: On Chrome, on firefox the buttons doesn't work at all

Comment: Can you add a fiddle?

Comment: There can be millions of reasons why it's that way. Providing a fiddle for it (or any means of inspecting it really) would be helpful

Comment: Possibly a conflict with your other CSS?  Try removing any custom CSS temporarily and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Those are my packages and are working fine, without the bootstrap-3 package was giving me strange errors too. Not sure about the less package, might be necessary.

```
standard-app-packages
preserve-inputs
iron-router
spin
roles
accounts-password
accounts-facebook
less
bootstrap-3
accounts-ui-bootstrap-3
jqueryui
d3
moment
```

[image]